# How can I get Avast Business to satisfy the wait parameter when its finished installing?

Tags: powershell, automation

I'm attempting to automate the installation of nine different pieces of software that we put on every teacher machine at the school I work at using PowerShell. So far I've managed to get every program to install automatically with no need for any user input except for one, Avast Business. Every time I try to install it, it runs through the installation process and then just sits there waiting for user input. Because of this, the script won't continue until I manually click the "close" button.

I've done a lot of research on this but have found very few results even remotely pointing to a solution. The best I've been able to manage is to determine that maybe the software isn't returning an exit code to PowerShell when its done installing and as such the -Wait parameter doesn't get satisfied, meaning PowerShell can't continue the script.

Below is the code I'm using to install Avast (the other pieces of software use very similar code, occassionally adding some additional arguments to make them run silently, something I couldn't find for Avast at all), along with some aesthetics to pretty things up in the PowerShell window.

```
# Install Avast Business
Write-Output " > Installing Avast Business"
Write-Output ""
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\autosetup\installers\AVAST_Business_Agent_setup_online.exe" -Wait -NoNewWindow
Stop-Process -Name "*setup*"
```

I intended for it to install, receive the exit code (at least I believe that's how that works) and then move on with the "Stop-Process" cmdlet closing any open windows. This has worked fine for everything else (Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, Microsoft Office, etc). Any help would be greatly appreciated as this has boggled my mind for about a week now. If I need to add anymore information to clarify anything please let me know.

Comment: Are you using the paid version of Avast? If you are then you should have access to the .MSI installer, with which you can do a silent install using the /qb switch.

Comment: We are using the paid version. We have the business license for I think like 600 devices or so. I've just been trying to make it work with the installer that my predecessor used but if there is a MSI installer I'll give that a shot.